# How to make secrets set by non-admin user inaccessible by aws administrator?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have a requirement in **AWS**. A non-admin user needs to write certain secrets inside ***AWS Secrets Manager***. These secrets should not be accessible to the AWS **administrator**.

Here AWS administrator is the one who has "AdministratorAccess" policy attached to the user and non-admin is the user created by the admin and granted only limited access to some of the services.

I want to store "username and password" of my application inside the secrets manager. The same credentials will be used by ***AWS Lambda*** as well.

The following policy I could write:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789011:user/app-admin-user"},
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789011:user/aws-admin-user"},
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this policy denies only single user. I want to deny all the AWS administrators in the account in the single policy.

Instead of `Principal` I tried writing `NotPrincipal` with only `app-admin-user` as follows:

```
{
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "NotPrincipal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789011:user/app-admin-user"},
            "Resource": "*"
 }
```

But this gives `AccessDeniedException` saying `User does not have permission to specify explicit deny` as the user `app-admin-user` is not AWS administrator.

I am attaching this policy document with the secret I am creating.

Do suggest if any alternate solution is available apart from using ***AWS Secrets Manager*** to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) describes how you can limit access to an S3 bucket to a specific IAM role by utilising `Conditions` rather than a `NotPrincipal`.

You can apply the same logic to `secretsmanager`, to restrict access to any IAM user which doesn't match the user Id pattern:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*",
            "AIDAEXAMPLEID",
            "111111111111"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the `userId` of an IAM user, run the `aws iam get-user -–user-name USER-NAME` command.

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a couple of years, but you have NO IDEA how much this answer saved my life. The AWS permissions system is all setup to deny whenever there's an explicit deny, which left me super confused when I needed to exclude all administrators except for me from an action they could do by default. Searched for awhile and got nowhere - this really saved me!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, glad to hear it helped :)